# How to achieve # in URL after submiting form?

Tags: javascript, url-rewriting

I have to submit a form which opens next page, but URL in next page has to be #/indes/string.

I have a page with input box and button. I already have logic to open new page, transfer parameter via:

```
var inputStr = document.getElementById('input_box').value;
var w = window.open("indes.html", '_blank');
w.input = inputStr;
```

and show it on new page with

```
<script> document.write(input);</script>
```

But I have to input this "string" to URL so the URL looks like:

```
#/indes/string
```

My URL should look like this at the end: www.mydomain.com/#/indes/string

How can I do this? Is this URL-rewriting? Can I even use this on my WAMP?

Comment: It is very hard to understand what you are asking. Also I do not understand why you use document.write and where. - also you have two versions of the hash - #/page2/parameters and #/indes/string. If you do window.open("indes.html#/page2/parameters"), the location.hash should contain the parameters

Comment: document.write is used in second page, the one that opens when i press submit. Its a test that string from input box is really pushed forward from first page to second page.
Also, my URL should look like this at the end: www.mydomain.com/#/indes/string

Answer (score 0):

Check out [sammy](http://sammyjs.org/)

Seems just like the thing you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set the Location Hash Property by setting `window.location.hash`.

Answer (score 0):

instead of open a new window use location.hash but make sure you prevent default behavior by return false or if you use jquery use preventdefault.

```
function() {
  [your logic]
  location.hash = "#/indes/string";
  return false
}
```